# Why do you need to shift bits when reading from an analog sensor?

Tags: sensors, analogread, raspberrypi

I was playing around with some analog grove sensors and looking at examples (https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/master/Software/Go/grovepi/grovepi.go - this specific example is in go and for raspberry pi, but it's the same on arduino) I realised that you need to "(int(val[1]) << 8) | int(val[2])" before getting the result.

Why is that so? Why do the second 8 bits need to be left shifted by 8 and why is there then an OR with the third group of bits?

Comment: ... Because you read one byte at a time.

Comment: Can you be more specific? When Read() is called, my array of bytes is filled right away, why do I need this operation afterwards?

Comment: Because now you need a number. 123 = 100 + 20 + 3

Comment: Alright, but why are we not using the first 4 bytes?

Comment: This seems to be a good documentation of the protocol; https://www.dexterindustries.com/GrovePi/programming/grovepi-protocol-adding-custom-sensors/

Comment: with color sensor nothing is skiped. it is sensor device specific. if the first 4 bytes from the device are not useful they are skipped. ask an arduino question.

Comment: It's about reconstructing the bytes of an int into the int itself. If you Google be read about "big endian", "little endian" and "network byte order" it may help you to understand what's going on.

Comment: what sensor it is? "analog"? it is i2c protocol in the link. is it an ADC sensor or why do you call it "analog".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read bytes in the order:

- Most significant byte   (let's call this msb)
- Least significant byte  (let's call this lsb)

The formula to get to real value is msb * 256 + lsb
256 because this is the value of the maximum value of one byte, + 1. which is bits (2 ^ 8 = 256).

However, a CPU is normally faster in bit operations than in arithmetic operations.

```
Assume msb is 10101010
and lsb is    11001100
```

Now below is the table with the calculation order

```
sensor value             msb         lsb
00000000 00000000        10101010    11001100
00000000 10101010                                sensor value = msb
10101010 00000000                                msb << 8, or msb * 256
10101010 11001100                                (msb << 8) + lsb, or (msb * 256) + lsb
```

Actually I would expect a cast to an unsigned byte type (8 bits). However, if the values msb or lsb would be floating points/doubles, than the remainder will be removed, leaving an integer (whole) number.

Comment: Great, thanks! But why is this only for the analog read? It doesn't seem like they do it for the digital one

Comment: I don't know ... it depends on the order in which the bytes are received.

Comment: I still think you do not know what you do. You write about analog, but there is nothing analog in that sensor's interface.

Comment: @Juraj Thank you for your contribution, however I believe this community was created for people who do not know what they're doing. If I did I would have written a blog post instead of asking a question.

Comment: but I could explain if you would disclose the type of the sensor

Comment: "why...only for the analog read?" It is due to the design of the device's interface, regardless of what kind of data is being passed. An 8-bit MCU can only pass 1 byte at a time so any quantity larger than that must be transmitted to it byte-by-byte and reassembled by it once it has been received. Shifting is part of the reassembly - it puts each byte back in into its proper place within the larger (16-bits / 2 bytes in your case) number.